# static variable value lost in webrole

Tags: webrole

```
>  public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
>     {
>         public static int x;
>         public override bool OnStart()
>         {
>            x=5;    
>            return base.OnStart();
>         }
>     }
```

If I try to get WebRole.x value it is 0, even though it was initialized to 5 in the OnStart method. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Just checking as there may be a better method in windows azure.

And I'm only theorizing here, but I'm guessing that when you go to retrieve the value, you're actually getting a new copy of the object that resides in a seperate process. As such, the value of the object instance that you set during role startup isn't accessible.

Comment: The x should be a client proxy used by the webrole to access a webservice. I guess it is better to keep it in global.asax, so I don't need to recreate the proxy on each request? what's your opinion on this?

Comment: I'd agree. the OnStart is best used for any tasks that need to be executed before your role starts. Depending on the nature of the proxy, you may also be able to place it into cache. But only do this is you aren't concerned about data bleeding over between request processes.

Answer (score -3):

A `static` field does not belong to the instance of the object.  Remove `static`.

Comment: what he meant was to create a global variable.. if he removes static then anywayz the data that needs to be persisted is lost